# How to change pagination in Datatables on key events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am using Datatables jQuery plugin to display data. Here is what I need:

- When the user gives input to the search box the pagination goes away and shows all the records at once.
- When the user clears the search box the table should go back to its original state with the pagination, etc.

Is there a way to do this? I've tried doing the following:

```
var $dt = $('#datatable').DataTable();
$("input[type=search]").keyup(function() {
    var search_string = $(this).val();
    if(search_string.length > 0) {
        $dt.destroy();
        $('#datatable').DataTable({
            "paging": false
        });
    } else {
        $('#datatable').DataTable();
    }           
});
```

But after I start typing, the Datatable reloads and the cursor is not inside the search box.

Comment: Not that familiar with codeignitor, but that shouldn't really matter - can't you just do a `.destroy()` on the table when you search, with new options, and then put back the original options when you remove the search?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie Please see my edit.

Comment: ah. Right. What if you don't call `destroy()` first? Just set pagination to false?

Comment: how do I do that ? Without calling DataTable()

Comment: Just remove the `$('#datatable').DataTable().destroy();` line, and test?

Comment: I get error alert saying `cannot reinitialize DataTable()`

Comment: Ah, right... you can't call `.DataTable()` on an already initialized one, of course... too long since I've worked with datatables, it seems. Seems dynamically changing the datatables value is a bit tricky - perhaps you can circumvent the problem by storing the search-value (the input) in a variable, destroy and repopulate the table, and set focus to the search-element, in the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$('#datatable').DataTable().page.len(-1).draw();
```

to change table page length. Example:

```
var $dt = $('#datatable').DataTable();
$("input[type=search]").keyup(function() {
    var search_string = $(this).val();
    if(search_string.length > 0) {
        // Show all records on one page.
        $dt.page.len(-1).draw();
    } else {
        // Reset page length.
        $dt.page.len(10).draw();
    }           
});
```

Source: https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.len()